# How to add HTML templates in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I made an template of a price box, and I want that every time that I click a button a new price box shows up in the page. 
Just a simple example for my template:

```
<div>
  <h1> Product: {productName} </h1>
</div>
```

And everytime that I click a button, I pass the name and this template will show in the page.

I was looking and I saw the template tag with javascript and another solutions like Mustache. Which approach would be better and more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your asking but this would be very simple using pure javascript. Please see the following code snippet:

```js
function addProduct() {
  const productName = document.querySelector('#productName').value;
  productName ? document.querySelector('#products').innerHTML += `
<div><h1>Product: ${productName}</h1></div>
` : alert('Enter Product Name');
}

document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', () => addProduct());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="productName">
<button id="add">Add Product</button>
<div id="products"></div>
```

Comment: It's just like that, but my template can very long, so I wanted a more readable way instead of doing using quotes

Comment: Yes, because I think that if I just add a lot of html my code can become polluted. And I'll probably need to use escapes in strings for classes and other thing so this can turn very arduous

Comment: @JasonMort Not sure why you think html in your js === pollution. With string templates everything looks relatively nice compared to the old `'<div>' + variable + '</div>'` method.

Comment: However if you absolutely want to separate things and are not averse to using a framework. Angular is my favorite. VueJS and React are great ones too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use template tag?

Comment: Not necessarily.